# HP LaserJet 1018 doesn't work under ubuntu 15.04

Tags: printing, 15.04, hp

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and an HP LaserJet 1018 connected by USB. Ubuntu has found drivers and shows that everything is OK. When I send test page to printer it shows that it was handled first and than operation completed but nothing actually happens.

Can somebody help me? I'm new in using Ubuntu. Maybe I do something wrong...

Comment: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Comment: I've installed this software and tried to use it, but behaviour after installation is the same and how I understood it uses cups as under layer

Comment: Not sure how it look with HPLIP, I have samsung printer, but try to click Printer properties ----> entry with name "Make and Model" ----> change ----> select printer from the database -----> look for your model and  HPLIP driver. In my case I have two drivers for my printer, Ubuntu one - which shows the same behaviour as in your case and the other ( you will look for HPLIP driver).

Comment: I have Ubuntu Mate, so it might look a little different on other flavours.

Comment: Hplip toolbox has diagnose hplip driver function. Try it.

Comment: When I run hp-toolbox I get next warning message:

"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
  set_interactive(1)"

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. Go on terminal and type `sudo hp-setup`. It will add the printer to your system and ask for necessary plugin to be installed and prepared to use.

Comment: I've installed with ```sudo hp-setup -i```